# How to rename files pulled from a list of files using a single command or line

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, rename

I have a project named `my-project` with the following file tree.

my-project/ (before)

```
.
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── normalize.js
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── Home
│   │       ├── index.js
│   │       └── assets
│   ├── static
│   ├── store
│   │   ├── createStore.js
│   │   └── reducers.js
│   └── styles
└── project.config.js
```

Now, I want to **rename the following files** to add the string `-orig` immediately before the filetype extension.

files-to-rename.txt

```
src/main.js
src/routes/index.js
src/store/reducers.js
project.config.js
```

(I do not want to change any of the file contents at all.)

So the final file tree looks like the following.

my-project/ (after)

```
.
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main-orig.js
│   ├── normalize.js
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index-orig.js
│   │   └── Home
│   │       ├── index.js
│   │       └── assets
│   ├── static
│   ├── store
│   │   ├── createStore.js
│   │   └── reducers-orig.js
│   └── styles
└── project.config-orig.js
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with a single line or command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bash`:

```
while read ; do mv "$REPLY" "${REPLY%.js}-orig.js" ; done < files-to-rename.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to ask the shell to read each line from the file, then use shell parameter expansion to extract the base filename and the extension:

```
while IFS= read -r filename
do
  base=${filename%.*}
  extension=${filename##*.}
  echo mv -- "my-project/$filename" "my-project/${base}-orig.${extension}"
done < files-to-rename.txt
```

Remove the `echo` if the output looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `cat files-to-rename.txt`; do postfix=${i/#*\./}; mv $i ${i/%.$postfix/-orig.$postfix}; done;
```

this works with arbitrary postfix, not just js.  however, please use try git or svn for your own sake.  even a tar command will work better than this.

Comment: The `for i in \`cat ...\``thing will not work with filenames containing spaces. You'd need `IFS='\n'`, or use `read`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `rename` command.  First do a verbose test run that changes nothing:

```
rename -n -v 's/.js$/-orig.js/' $(find my-project/)
```

If that seems correct, remove the `-n` to actually rename the files:

```
rename    -v 's/.js$/-orig.js/' $(find my-project/)
```

---

Note: to install `rename` on a *Debian* or *Ubuntu* box, do:

```
apt install rename
```